# For a given natural number $s$, are there infinitely many primes with form $2st+1,t\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory

I know that this holds for $s=1,2$, but I'd like to know whether this generalized version holds or not. If this doesn't hold, how about the weaker case which replaces "a given natural number" with "infinitely many natural numbers"?

Comment: You probably want to take a look at the Dirichlet theorem on primes in arithmetic progression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; this is a special case of [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), which says that for any given $a$ and $b$ there are an infinite number of primes of the form $an+b$, except when $a$ and $b$ have a common factor greater than 1.

In particular, there are an infinite number of primes of the form $an+1$ for any $a$.

Answer (score 3):

Although I can't deny that this indeed is a special case of Dirichlet's theorem, I wanted to point out that the special case of $an+1$ has a very elementary proof using cyclotomic polynomials, and can be seen e.g. [here](http://www.yimin-ge.com/doc/cyclotomic_polynomials.pdf) (Theorem 8).